# How to flash android AOSP 10 to device?

Tags: aosp, android-10

I used to run Android AOSP 6.1 on my Nexus 5 by manually flashing the boot, cache, system, userdata, recovery images one by one using fastboot. I managed to successfully flash Android 6.1 on my Nexus 5 following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m5BMfvO9Xi0

I have managed to build Android AOSP 10 and my goal is to flash it to my Pixel 2. First thing I noticed is that the output dir looks a bit different now. There are a few different images and there is no more recovery.img. The [Android 10 Factory 10 dir](https://developers.google.com/android/images#walleye) contains this images:

[image]

I tried to manually flash the boot, dtbo, system_other, system, vbmeta & vendor images but the device ends up in a boot loop.

Does anyone know how to flash the Android 10 AOSP images to a device?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recovery is now built into the boot image instead of having a separate partition. So, a separate recovery image does not exist.
The files you have are supposed to be flashed to their respective partitions:

Boot to boot, 
System to system, 
Vendor to vendor, 
Vbmeta to vbmeta, 
Dtbo to dtbo

You can avoid the system_other as it is to build a dummy into your inactive boot slot. It isn't actually used. But if you want, you can flash it to the inactive slot. You check current active slot by using this command: `fastboot getvar current-slot`. Then flash to that slot by adding the slot suffix (example: If current slot is a, flash it to b - `fastboot flash system_b system_other.img`

Remember that you need to perform a wipe of internal storage from either fastboot (`fastboot -w`) or by going into the Android Recovery mode.